# Java- Cannot find symbol of a class defined in another file but belonging to the same package

Tags: java, class, oop, package

So I am currently learning OOP in java. I created a java package called circleClass and made two java class files. The Circle.java contains the Circle class and circleDemo.java is trying to create a Circle object.

Circle File

```
package circleClass;

public class Circle {
    double radius = 1.0;
    String color = "blue";

    Circle(){
        this.radius = 1;
        this.color = "blue";
    }

    Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    double getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }

    double getArea() {
        return this.radius * this.radius * 3.14;
    }
}
```

circleDemo File

```
package circleClass;
public class circleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        System.out.println("The area of the circle c1 is = " + c1.getArea());
        Circle c2 = new Circle(10);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle c2 is = " + c2.getArea());
        Circle c3 = new Circle(20);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle c3 is = " + c3.getArea());
    }
}
```

However whenever I try to compile circleDemo.java, it gives the following error:

```
circleDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Circle c1 = new Circle();
                ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class circleDemo
circleDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Circle c1 = new Circle();
                                ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class circleDemo
```

The Circle.java file is already compiled and created a Circle.class file. Also, do I need to import the file if they belong to the same package or not?

I tried making all the constructors and methods in the Circle class public but it did not have any effect. I tried importing the Circle class but it just showed the the import statement is never used.

Please help. I am new to the field and am using VS Code.

Edit:
I found the above error only occurred when I use the run code option of code editor. But if I use run java or debug java from Java Debugger extension, it runs perfectly. Why does that happen? Is it a java thing or a VS Code thing?

Comment: How does your project structure look?

Comment: Both java and class files are in the same package

Answer (score 0):

since you compiled Circle.java already and it's in the package circleClass, for other classes using the circleClass.Circle class, during compilation they'll try and find classes in the folder you're compiling from.

To compile you have two options.

1. Compile both classes together. From the folder circleClass, you can run `javac *.java`
2. Or if you already have the Circle class compiled, make sure you have the  folder circleDemo in classpath before compiling circleDemo.
   `javac -cp ../ circleDemo.java`